# Testing a directive in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have a directive in angular that dynamically creates 5 buttons. I am currently writing unit tests and I decided to write one that tests if all the buttons are present. However I cannot seem to get the test to pass.
Here is some of my code.

Test.js:

```
    beforeEach(inject(function($compile,$rootScope,$location,$httpBackend,$route) {

    location = $location;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    route = $route;

    $httpBackend.whenGET('partials/options/options-skeleton.html')
                .respond(200);
    elm = angular.element("<options></options>");


    httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    $compile(elm)(scope);
    scope.$digest();

}));
describe('initial value test', function(){

    it('should have 5 buttons', function(){
        var options = elm.find('div');
        var innerElm = options.find('div');
        expect(innerElm.length).to.equal(5);
    });
});
```

Directive html:

```
<div class="row row-100" style=";margin-bottom: 20px">
      <div style="" class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 columns">
           <ul id="options-button-wrapper">
              <li ng-repeat="option in options.optionsArray track by $index">
                 <md-button aria-label="{{option}}" class="md-raised option-button" md-theme="green" ng-disabled="disableAllOptions">{{option}}</md-button>
              </li>
           </ul>
      </div>
</div>
```

The output I keep getting is:

```
AssertionError: expected 0 to equal 5
```

I have tried using JSON.stringify() on var options in the test to see what element it was set to but I kept getting an error:

```
TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures.
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. And if anymore code is needed please just let me know and I will update my question. Thanks in advance.

Update:

I have tried logging out

```
console.log(angular.element("<options></options>"));
```

and the output is:

```
LOG: {0: <options></options>, length: 1}
```

I assumed that using:

```
$compile(elm)(scope);
```

would cause the directive to be initialized and for the log to output the templateUrl that is loaded via the directive.

Comment: And how does `options.optionsArray` comes to the directive? It seems that you never define it in your test, so `ng-repeat` has nothing to repeat, therefore it does not create `<li>`s.

Comment: OK I updated my question. so now I look for <div>'s that are nested in another <div>. They are created regardless of whether or not ng-repeat runs. When I run the above code I still get 'expected 0 to equal 5'.

Comment: I wonder if your directive html is reached at all, because you've mocked a request to a template by `$httpBackend.whenGET('partials/options/options-skeleton.html').respond(200);`

Comment: Yes that seems like a possible explanation. I'm going to give html2js and $templateCache a go and see if that helps. I will update this question either way.